# What is the difference between C# and Node.js Console output?

Tags: c#, node.js, cmd, console-application, console.log

I'm using the `Console` API from C# and find a difference between the `Console` API from Node.js when try to use console commands to change color (`\x1B[31m'):

Using Node.js this code:

```
 console.log("\x1B[31mTeste");
```

Prints this:
[image: console with Teste in red]

---

When I use this C# code:

```
Console.Write("\x1B[31mTeste");
```

I get this output:
[image: console with some chars and Teste in default color]

---

Why have this difference?

Comment: yes, I know that x1B[31m is a code for terminal change color.. I just don't understand why c# don't work with this. (I will edit my question to make this more clear)

Comment: @KeithNicholas he is using AnsiCon there.. I'm using the default cmd from Windows

Comment: I know....  but node emulates a console, so you need something to do the same from Console.Write ....

Comment: node uses https://github.com/libuv/libuv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node uses https://github.com/libuv/libuv to emulate an ANSI console. The normal windows console doesn't support this, therefore trying to do it from C# won't work.

Comment: The console in Windows 10 supports virtual terminal sequences, but it has to be enabled first via WinAPI `GetConsoleMode` and `SetConsoleMode`. In older versions you can use ANSICON or ConEmu, which use DLL injection to hook WinAPI console functions such as `WriteConsole`.